# JavaScript Change RGB Value of a Single Pixel

Tags: javascript, pixel

I want to develop an online game in JavaScript, except I need a way to change the RGB value of a single pixel. Anyone know how to do this?

Thanks

Comment: A single pixel on a `<canvas>`?

Comment: You need to present code here, not a requirement list and then ask us to build it for you.

Comment: What's canvas? And: What code should I present? I really have no idea how to do this.

Comment: Neither have you an idea what you need. Where do you need to change a pixel? Do you at least know how to display your game on a website?

Comment: [<canvas>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Canvas) is an html element that can be used to draw on. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Canvas_tutorial) has a tutorial on using it. Note: some older browsers like the earlier versions of IE do not support the <canvas> element

Comment: Bergi: I need to change a pixel at specified coordinates. And, yes, I know how to display my game in a website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The canvas people are referring to is the HTML5 canvas tag: http://www.w3schools.com/HTML/html5_canvas.asp This is the main component used for creating animations and graphics in modern online games using JavaScript. Here is a good starting point: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/gg589490(v=vs.85).aspx

If you want to change the color of single pixel using a canvas you simply would draw a pixel by 1 pixel rectangle at a location. For example:

```
<html>
<body>

<canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="200" style="border:1px solid #c3c3c3;"></canvas>

<script>

var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillStyle="#FF0000";
ctx.fillRect(100,100,1,1);

</script>

</body>
</html>
```